# Whats the difference between main.storyboard and launchscreen.storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode

I don't know what to put in each. Can i just put my entire UI in one of them, will it matter?

Comment: dont put your entire UI into one storyboard, each storyboard should hold a logical segment of your entire app (make other ones that link up to your main storyboard), it will become a pain to edit the storyboard later on if you have 100 viewcontrollers in it (becomes very sluggish and difficult to manage)

Comment: The launchscreen.storyboard (basically a loading screen) is what comes up when the user loads the application. How long it appears to the user depends on how long it takes for the user to load your application. You can change the duration of the launchscreen.storyboard but it is not recommended, generally users want the app to load as fast as possible

The main.storyboard is appears onto the screen AFTER the launchscreen.storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Launchscreen.storyboard is just a static launch screen, you can't add any code or class into it. 
main.storyboard is all your app logic and you can make UI in there.